# MySQL query, comparing datetime

Tags: php, mysql

In my page user can register with email and subscribe for news. I'm putting email, IP and timestamp into my database. I want to make sure that one IP can only get 5 emails per day and I don't want the same email addresses in my database.

I tried this but it doesn't work, I can post as many as I want.

```
if(isset($_POST["send"]))
{
    $email = test_input($_POST['email']);
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
    $query = 'INSERT INTO subscriber (data, ip, email) (SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'", "'.$email.'" FROM dual where NOT EXISTS ( Select count(email) as c  FROM (
    SELECT email FROM subscriber  WHERE ip="'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'" and DATE(`data`) = CURDATE() group by email) as a having c>5))';
    $result =  mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
    $msg="E-mail sent successfully";
} else
{
    $msg="Wrong e-mail address";
}
```

And not to write same emails i should use something like this after insert?

FROM dual
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT * FROM subscriber
            WHERE email="'.$email.'"
        )';

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just separate the queries.
First check for

```
SELECT count(id) FROM subscriber  
WHERE ip="'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'" 
and DATE(`data`) = CURDATE()
```

And if the result is < 5 then do the insert. It will be simple and readable.

The whole code:

```
if(isset($_POST["send"])){

$email = test_input($_POST['email']);
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
    $query = 'SELECT count(id) FROM subscriber  
              WHERE ip="'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'" 
              and DATE(`data`) = CURDATE()';
    $result =  mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    $count  = mysqli_fetch_field($result);

    if($count < 5) {
        $query = "SELECT id FROM subscriber  
                  WHERE email='".$email."'
                  LIMIT 1";
        $result =  mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
        $mailExist = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if($mailExist > 0) {
            $msg="E-mail is already existing in the DB";
        }
        else {
            $query = "INSERT INTO subscriber (data, ip, email) VALUES (CURDATE(), '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."', '".$email."')";
            mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
            $msg="E-mail sent successfully";
        }
    }
    else {
        $msg="5 emails today";
    }
}
else {
    $msg="Wrong e-mail address";
}
```

It will be good if you put indexes on this fields in DB.
But I will advise you to use PDO instead of mysqli. You can read more about it here http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Can you please write me all query? Its a little bit difficult for me :D

Comment: Yes, thanks, and one more thing i need is not to write same emails into database... Check my edited question

Comment: It always say that email is already existing... Maybe something is wrong with my database table? I really believe that your code should work...

Comment: var_dump($mailExist) ?

Comment: Object of class could not be converted to int, its error like this

Comment: Ok, thanks, got it. My last edit should work. `mysqli_num_rows`

Comment: I found a mistake, you use select count and then you are comparing your rows(which is always 1), so i changed select count to just select and it works, thanks.

Comment: Yes :), that`s why I changed it with mysqli_num_rows and select id

Answer (score 1):

You should not GROUP BY email, when you want to count all emails from the same IP.

So your fixed query would be:

```
INSERT INTO subscriber (data, ip, email)
    SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, {$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}, {$email} 
    FROM dual 
    where NOT EXISTS (
        Select count(email) as c  
        FROM (
            SELECT email
            FROM subscriber  
            WHERE ip={$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']} 
              and DATE(`data`) = CURDATE() 
        ) as a 
        having c>=5
    )
```

You can also write it another way

```
INSERT INTO subscriber (data, ip, email)
    SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, {$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}, {$email} 
    FROM dual 
    where NOT EXISTS (
        Select count(email) as c  
        FROM subscriber  
        WHERE ip={$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']} 
          and DATE(`data`) = CURDATE() 
        having c>=5
    )
```

Or this way:

```
INSERT INTO subscriber (data, ip, email)
    SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, {$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}, {$email} 
    FROM dual 
    where 5 < (
        Select count(email) as c  
        FROM subscriber  
        WHERE ip={$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']} 
          and DATE(`data`) = CURDATE() 
    )
```